# Introduction to Debugging Compiled Languages for MATLAB Users

Tags: c++, python, matlab, debugging, fortran

I've used MATLAB for ages and am quite proficient. I'm used to MATLAB debugging where you can skip lines and see the variables and how they change, and that's how I learned to code. I'm now looking at numerous other programs I work with, such as SWAN, which were written in FORTRAN, C++ and Python.

I know you can debug in these languages; I just can't find an introduction to it as it seems much more complicated and different to MATLAB debugging. For example, in FORTRAN I know one of my colleagues has different versions of the software for execution and debugging.

Does anyone know of any guide to introduction to debugging in compiled languages? What programs are used to debug fortran source code? Is there an extensive documentation for beginners for such programs? I've tried to look up tutorials for things like Makefiles and there's alot of assumed background knowledge, which I'm guessing anyone with like 1 intro course to computer programming would know. Unfortunately, I'm a coastal engineer and all my programming I learned in numerical analysis course using MATLAB to solve the problems.

Thanks

Edit 001:

Im running Windows 7,Red Hat Linux, and OpenSuse Linux.

Comment: I've tried to improve the formatting of your question somewhat.  If it doesn't suit you, I'm happy to rollback the changes. :)

Comment: No I think it was a good edit. Thanks, Ill try and ask questions like this in the future because I know peeps prefer it.

Comment: *people :) This is how I prefer it.

Comment: It will be very helpful if you specify your operating system, since things are quite different on linux, windows and OS X.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stanford University offers [free online courses](http://online.stanford.edu/) in all disciplines. Have a look at their [course catalog](http://online.stanford.edu/courses/catalog). One relevant course is the "self-paced" [Programming Methodology](https://itunes.apple.com/us/course/programming-methodology/id495054181) course, accessible on iTunes curiously, which includes a section on debugging.

Similar to Standford's offering, Harvard University has what they call their ["Open Learning Initiative"](http://www.extension.harvard.edu/open-learning-initiative), a variety of free courses.  Of interest may be the [Intensive Introduction to Computer Science](http://www.extension.harvard.edu/open-learning-initiative/intensive-introduction-computer-science). Note that these courses generally comprise recorded lectures and can usually be watched online at your leisure. In fact, at the previous link there are two videos on debugging that you can watch (or listen to) right now.

Once you get the hang of debugging in one language, it will be easier to transition to others.

As an aside note, you might get comments that Python is interpreted rather than compiled, but seeing as it is compiled to bytecode at (just before) runtime, it is safe to say that it is compiled assuming a current mainstream implementation.

Keep this question open for a while since I'm sure you will get lots of good suggestions from people who *actually use* FORTRAN and Python. As for C++, I can't complain about the VS debugger and there are tons of resources, pages, videos on that.

From a MATLAB users' point of view, debugging C++ in VS might be frustrating since it is hard to run arbitrary commands when stopped at a breakpoint. There is an option for the Debug Information Format setting called Program Database for Edit and Continue that allows you to change your source while debugging and apply the changes to the application you are debugging, but a little think-first-code-later is probably more beneficial.

You may also want to look at [static code analysis tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis) to potentially catch certain problems without running the program (and the minor inconvenience of having your program crash to discover them)!

Answer (score 1):

Debugging Fortran in most cases is easily done by using single

```
print*, <variable>
```

statments. For more complicated problems a good debugger is GDB. To use it you have to compile your program with the degub FLAG (in case of gfortran it's -g). For GDB plenty of HowTo's can be found online. A free but not bug free frontend for GDB is DDD.

Comment: Another frontends are `kdbg`, `nemiver`, `Intel Debugger` and others. `valgrind` is also very useful to debug memory access errors and uninitialized variables.